# AWS Access Key not working in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a rails app setup with paperclip and aws-sdk

My aws.yml file is below:

```
development:
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

production:
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
```

My development.rb file is here:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
        :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
    }
}
```

I'm 100% sure my keys are correct. I've double, triple and quadruple checked the keys. I first tried an Iam user key, but that didn't work, then I tried creating a root key and that didn't work either. I'm back to using a brand new Iam user key and that user has full S3 access.

/config/initializers/algoliasearch.rb uses an environment variable just fine:

```
AlgoliaSearch.configuration = { application_id: 'xxxxxx', api_key: ENV['algolia_admin_api_key'] }
```

Still, though, when I try to upload a file in my development environment I get the InvalidAccessKey error from aws. I haven't tried it on production yet because that's using the same keys (just the bucket name is different).

Am I using the wrong keys? Or is something preventing my key from being accessed? I can't find anything telling me how to set my keys up properly and I'm completely lost. I know I got this working before and can't remember there being any other steps.

Comment: copy/paste error? `ENV['AWS_BUCKET'` should be `ENV['AWS_BUCKET']`.

Comment: Where is the ENV variable set?

Comment: @JustinLicata that was an error in posting here. It's correct in the code. I'll update the original post.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti they're set in the OS via the .profile file. When pushing to production I'll set them in the OS there as well.

Comment: The user running the web process may not be the one you configured the `.profile`. Generally, it's either root, www-data or some sort of superuser process which doesn't inherit the same configs from the .profile.

Comment: Try to start your app like this and see whether it works: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_id AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_key AWS_BUCKET=your-bucket rails s Of course, you will have to substitute your id, key, and bucket.

Comment: @Gen I did `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx rails s -b 0.0.0.0` 
and that didn't work (I need `-b 0.0.0.0` because I'm building this on Koding). I'm not sure if I did something wrong. I hard coded the keys into my aws.yml file and it worked just fine so I think @SimoneCarletti's probably on the right course here.

Comment: You forgot AWS_BUCKET=xxxxxxxxx or at least you did not mention it. If passing params from command line does not work... then you really in trouble :)

Comment: I'll pull the repository to my local machine and try that out. I think it'll work there

Comment: Just confirmed that it doesn't work on my local machine. Also I remembered that I have another reference to an environment variable in one of my initializers and that's been working all the time. 
When I hardcode the keys into my aws.yml file everything uploads perfectly, but not with I reference the environment variable. I have no idea what the issue could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution: I had to add the s3 credentials to the production.rb and development.rb environment files:

```
# development.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
        :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
        :access_key_id => ENV['HOMEIN_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        :secret_access_key => ENV['HOMEIN_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
}
```

They're both the same, except for the bucket name.
I feel like there's a more elegant solution that I don't know of, though...